# APIConnectionError with Stripe API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to integrate the Stripe API in my Rails project. But I am wondering why I have a failed APIConnectionError when I have checked that my internet connection is fine.

In `users_controller.rb`:

```
def charge
  token = params["stripeToken"]
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    source: token,
    plan: 'mysubscriptionlevel1',
    email: current_user.email
  )

  current_user.subscription.stripe_user_id = customer.id
  current_user.subscription.active = true
  current_user.subscription.save

  redirect_to users_info_path
end
```

In the `/views/users/_form.html.erb`, I have the form POST-ing to the `/users/charge` url path.

```
  <h4>Begin your £9.99 a month subscription</h4>
  <form action="/users/charge" method="POST" id="payment-form">
    <span class="payment-errors"></span>
```

And in my `routes.rb` file, I have:

```
post '/users/charge', to: 'users#charge'
```

In `config/initializer/stripe.rb`, I have required stripe and put my api key in the .env file.

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
```

I have also included the `stripe` gem in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'dotenv-rails', :groups => [:development, :test]
```

I am not sure what I am missing and this is the error that I get when I call the `charge` action in `users_controller.rb`:

```
Stripe::APIConnectionError (Unexpected error communicating when trying to connect to Stripe. You may be seeing this message because your DNS is not working. To check, try running 'host stripe.com' from the command line.

(Network error: Failed to open TCP connection to : (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known))):
```

What does it mean by the DNS not working and how can I debug by just running 'host stripe.com'

Comment: any chance you're behind firewall?

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I switched the proxy and it works now.

Answer (score -4):

Switched the proxy and it now works.

Comment: I know it's been 2 years, but if by any chance you see this, can you explain just what you did? (What proxy did you use?)